# Use bash to determine files in Directrory A that do not exist in Directories B and C

Tags: bash, diff

I have a directory (Directory A) with files.

Directories B and C contain files from directory A (no files in B are in C and vice versa).

How can I list files in Directory A that are not present in Directories B nor C?

Comment: What kind of volume? Are we dealing with tens of thousands of files here, or only a few tens/hundreds?

Comment: ..and are these recursive directories? (Does Directory A have subdirectories containing files, etc.?)

Comment: Also, which platform? Do you have GNU `find`? Are you trying to support all POSIX-compliant platforms?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  Platform is Linux or Windows. I prefer Linux answers but can do it either way. We're dealing with about 100K files in total. Additionally, all files are PDFs.

Comment: @BenDeVries - These are non-recursive directories.

Comment: 100k files is enough that the `comm` approach will be considerably faster than the native-bash one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to be fast in very-high-volume cases:

```
for f_path in a/*; do f=${f_path#a/}
  [[ -e "b/$f" || -e "c/$f" ]] && continue
  printf '%s\n' "$f"
done
```

If you *do*, and have GNU `comm`, `find` and `sort`, see the following -- of course, replace the `tr` at the end with code that actually reads a NUL-delimited list properly if you want to be able to safely handle all possible filenames:

```
comm -z23 <(find a -maxdepth 1 -printf '%P\0' | sort -z) \
          <(find b c -maxdepth 1 -printf '%P\0' | sort -z) \
  | tr '\0' '\n'
```

For more on this use of `comm`, see [BashFAQ #36](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/036).

Comment: With the first solution (globbing), use `shopt -s nullglob` to handle an empty `a` directory correctly.  Also, use `shopt -s dotglob` if the files to be checked may have names that begin with a dot.